# Chinese xbox 360 receiver

Tags: gamepad, xbox-360

I used a Chinese xbox 360 controller receiver in windows and worked ok. Now I’ve switched to Ubuntu I can not find any information on how to install the receiver can anyone help

Comment: If there is more than one "Chinese xbox 360 controller receiver" made, it would probably help if you gave details about exactly what the model you have is.

Comment: you need to provide more info. if usb show like `lsusb` info. Check for vendor id and product id and search those online for compatibility.

Comment: Yes, and you need to be more specific. All controllers are Chinese, be it the original or the multitude of compatible ones.

Comment: Which vendor and product ID does your adapter use? See https://www.s-config.com/chinese-xbox-360-wireless-receiver-driver-setup/ for more information on these 3P Xbox 360 wireless receivers. The `xpad` driver already recognizes the IDs for the official adapter 045e:0719 and the XBOX-branded knockoff 045e:0219 but there could be more. If the receiver is dead it may display as 0000:0000. Note that "the third-party china receiver has no 250mA breaker fuse and thus are more prone to possible DOA from USB power spike upon plugin." Maybe it died when you plugged it in. Does it still work on Windows?